# Truncate statement issue in MySQL master slave replication

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, master-slave

I am using MySQL master slave replication. All the servers are using the version 5.6. The replication is in the format that Master A replicates to Slave B and Slave B replicates to Slave C.

I have issued a truncate table statement on the master and the changes got replicated on slave B, but not on Slave C. Can anyone explain logic behind this or if any configuration needs to be added.

All the 3 servers are using binlog-format MIXED.

Log_slave_update is set ON in Slave B

Comment: Even Create table statement also not being replicated to slave C

Comment: But the create statement is written to the relay log of slave C